# How does Email package decide whether to send html or text?

Tags: meteor

I would like to know how `Email` package chooses to send `html` or `text` version of an email.

The doc for `Email.send` says:

> ### Email.send(options)
>
> ...
>
> #### options
>
> ...
>
> #### text, html (String)
>
> Mail body (in plain text and/or HTML)

So it seems that we can supply both `text` and `html`. Any information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, Meteor's Email package uses [mailcomposer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailcomposer) for mail composition.

If the `options` object includes both `html` and `text`, both of them will be sent in a `multipart/alternative` content-type email massage and the email client will be able to choose which one to display (the HTML, for any modern client).

You can easily test this by sending some emails with text/html/both and look at their source.